# "This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace."

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

When using `<p:messages>` OR `<h:messages>`, I am getting the following warning:

> This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

I understand that it's just a warning but still it's a bit annoying when working in development mode.

Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Using: WebLogic 12c & primefaces 5

Comment: I assume its just a warning in your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also come from a `<p>` if you don't have declared the default XML namespace for HTML.

E.g.

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org.ui"
>
    <p><p:messages/></p>
</ui:composition>
```

Would produce this warning.

You'd need to add the default XML namespace for HTML.

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org.ui"
>
    <p><p:messages/></p>
</ui:composition>
```

This also totally explains why you still got the message when using `<h:messages>` instead.

Comment: Its look like the reason is because in my main template there are <div> & <p> tag’s

Comment: I know. The answer covered that. Is something still unclear now? If those `<div>`s were placed in front of `<p>`s you'd have gotten "with prefix div" in the error message instead which is perhaps a stronger hint that the default XML namespace for plain HTML elements was missing.